# How a low priority task will be executed in VxWorks

Tags: vxworks

Assume if low priority task is waiting to execute and higher priority tasks are continuously executing without giving a chance for the low priority task to execute. When the low priority task will be executed and how this scenario will be handled in VxWorks?

Answer (score 3):

If there are tasks with a higher priority than the low priority task executing, and they never give up the CPU, then the low priority task will **never** execute.

This is CPU starvation and is a design flaw your system - unless that's what you want.